# how to copy text type column values to image type column in same table

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I want to change my table data type text to image. So I thought first I will add new column with image type then will copy all data from old column to new with conversion text to image. Then drop the old column and rename new column with old name.

But while convert data text to image i getting following error.

> Explicit conversion from data type text to image is not allowed.

I tried following code to convert

```
Update dbo.customers Set [DescriptionImage] = CAST(Description as image)

 Update dbo.customers  Set [DescriptionImage] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CAST(Description AS IMAGE),0))
```

but both queries gave same error.

so how to convert column values text to image?

or is there any another way to do it?

Thank You

Comment: What makes you think you can store text in an image type field and why would you want to?

Comment: In my app I have simple editor but now I want rich text editor. So I need to convert existing records.

Comment: NO you do NOT want to do this. You need to use a proper datatype for whatever it is you are trying to do. Both the text and image datatypes have been deprecated for more than a decade in favor of varchar(max) and varbinary(max).

Comment: "Another way to do it" would be with a .net app or CLR proc.